# Why predict works without fit the model in Keras

Tags: python, keras

Check the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Data
X = np.random.rand(1000, 100, 1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 1))

# Splitting into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Conv1D
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())

# Predict before fitting the model
cnn_features_train = model.predict(X_train)
cnn_features_test = model.predict(X_test)
```

Why this runs without throwing an error? The weights are not yet stabilished by the `.fit` method, how can it predict something?

If i try to do the same thing (predict before fitting the model) using `Sklearn` i get the expected error, for example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Data
X = np.random.rand(1000, 100, 1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 1))

# Splitting into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Random Forest
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.predict(X_test)
```

The error:

```
 sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: The weights are established, they will follow whichever initialization procedure you use (I think Xavier is default in Keras), they just are not fit. Also, you're comparing two entirely different classification methods.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren Oh, i guess i understand now. By any chance do you know about the `MLPClassifier` initialization procedure? Tried to look into sklearn documentation, but didn't found anything. I ask this because it also does not work (predict before fitting), and i think it is not that different from a CNN?

Comment: I looked a little and the initialization is pretty thoroughly embedded into the fit() function of sklearn neural networks. While in principle you should be able to run predict on just random weights, since all the initialization is done in the fit() stage it's a big pain to extract it out and skip the fit().

Answer (score 0):

Keras is different from `sklearn`. The `.predict ()`without calling `.fit()` helps users in preparing and debugging the correct shapes of the tensor.